# Does moving have a negative impact on young children?

Tags: toddler, moving, separation

I'm wondering about the impact of moving homes on my daughter who is only 2 and a half.
My wife claims that it is better to stay in one place because of stability for our daughter. 
But I think that she is too young to even care so much. As long as she has her toys she is happy!
My parents moved house when I was about 2 years old and I can't even remember the original house.

So, I want to know if the move (which is within the same city) is going to impact on our daughter. I'm looking for specific research that backs your position, not just opinions, but am not sure where to look personally for this information.

Comment: See also this related question: [When is the best time in a child's development to move to a different area?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/1766)